# Annotate markers values on Seaborn line plot (sns)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, seaborn

is there a way to annotate the markers value on a Seaborn line plot?

**This is my actual line plot:**

```py
a4_dims = (20, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
p1 = sns.lineplot(x='NBags', y='value', hue='variable', style="variable", markers=True, dashes=False, 
             data=pd.melt(df_knn1, ['NBags']))
```

[image]

**And This is what I want:**
[image]

Where the numeric values on each marker is the value of the marker itself on the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `ax.text(...)`, by default the annotated text color is black. If you want to color group the labels, then a possible way is to do a groupby `ax.text(...)` loop (with your predefined color palette) as follows,

Import libraries and create a sample data frame

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.random.rand(15,3)
y = np.random.binomial(2, 0.5, (15,1))
z = np.concatenate((x,y),axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(z,columns=['x','y','mark_value','label'])
df['label'] = df['label'].astype(int)
print(df)
#            x         y  mark_value  label
# 0   0.929616  0.316376    0.183919      1
# 1   0.204560  0.567725    0.595545      1
# 2   0.964515  0.653177    0.748907      1
# 3   0.653570  0.747715    0.961307      1
# 4   0.008388  0.106444    0.298704      0
# 5   0.656411  0.809813    0.872176      1
# 6   0.964648  0.723685    0.642475      0
# 7   0.717454  0.467599    0.325585      2
# 8   0.439645  0.729689    0.994015      2
# 9   0.676874  0.790823    0.170914      1
# 10  0.026849  0.800370    0.903723      0
# 11  0.024676  0.491747    0.526255      1
# 12  0.596366  0.051958    0.895090      1
# 13  0.728266  0.818350    0.500223      2
# 14  0.810189  0.095969    0.218950      2
```

Code for plotting

```
a4_dims = (20, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)

palette = ['r','b','g']

p1 = sns.lineplot(x='x', y='y', hue='label', style='label', markers=True, dashes=False, 
             data=df, palette=palette)

for item, color in zip(df.groupby('label'),palette):
    #item[1] is a grouped data frame
    for x,y,m in item[1][['x','y','mark_value']].values:
        ax.text(x,y,f'{m:.2f}',color=color)
```

Output
[image]